# An initial-value problem and a corresponding Laplace Transform

Tags: calculus, integration, laplace-transform

I am to solve the 1st-order ODE 
\begin{align*}y^\prime + 3y = 45t, \qquad y(0) = 6
\end{align*} using a Laplace Transform for a problem set. So far, by taking the Laplace Transform of both sides, I have 
\begin{align*}sY(s) - y(0) + \dfrac{3}{y^2} = \dfrac{45}{t^2}.\end{align*}
However, apparently this is an incorrect form. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $Y(s)=\mathcal{L}\left \{ y(t) \right \}$. Taking the Laplace transform of the constant coefficient ODE results in the following
$$\left [ sY(s)-y(0)) \right ]+3\left [Y(s)  \right ]=\frac{45}{s^2}$$
Collecting like terms gives
$$(s+3)Y(s)=\frac{45}{s^2}+6$$
or after rearrangement
$$Y(s)=\frac{\frac{45}{s^2}+6}{s+3}$$

> **NOTE:** From the transform tables, I used the pair:
>
> - $t^n\leftrightarrow \frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$
>
> to invert the term on the right-hand side.

Comment: Wait, how is $\mathcal{L}\{3y\} = 3[Y(s)]$? Shouldn't it be $\dfrac{3}{y^2}$? Also, isn't $\mathcal{L}\{45t\} = \dfrac{45}{t^2}$ and not $\dfrac{45}{s^2}$?

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether, not it shouldn't. You can either look at the table of Laplace transforms or calculate it using the formula $\mathcal{L}\{ f(t)\} = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st} dt$, which should be a function of $s$.

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether: No.  $Y(s)=\mathcal{L}\left \{ y(t) \right \}$, by definition (see the integral that ZanCoul wrote.) Your argument it true if $y$ was $t$. Remember that $y$ is the dependent variable whereas $t$ is the variable that is being transformed to $s$.

Comment: My mistake, I wasn't reading close enough.

Comment: Okay but I still don't see how $\mathcal{L}\{3y\} = 3[Y(s)]$ given that $\mathcal{L}\{t\} = \dfrac{1}{s^2}$ on my Laplace Transform table.

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether Both results are correct and they are uncorrelated. It seems like you are confusing $t$ and $y(t)$, try to read the definition of the Laplace transform.